# Eclipse Spring Security Warning 'unable to load namespacehandler'

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, spring-security

I'm trying to create my first Spring/Maven web application using Eclipse and I've been getting this warning in my spring-security.xml configuration file that has been driving me nuts for days!

I've tried to find solutions from other people (since this seems like a common problem), but all the solutions I found didn't work to me. The most common one seem to be to add spring-security-config.jar in, but I've already got that.

Here is a picture of the warning. The same warning also appears next to the  if I add that in.

[image: Spring Security Warning Eclipse]

I have also tried adding -3.2 to both the beans and security .xsd as well as a combination of every other number I could think of.

These are my pom.xml dependencies:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.0.0.M1</spring.version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.0.M2</spring.security.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2.1</jstl.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring Security Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- JSTL Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>${jstl.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MySQL Database Driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And here is my web.xml:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="3.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

If anyone has any ideas what may be causing the warnings in eclipse, please feel free to let me know. If you need more information as well, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Clear the workspace and build again. Sometimes eclipse is giving false alarms..

Comment: Hi ritesh. I've already tried that by going to Project -> Clean in Eclipse. This is actually the 2nd time I've remade the project from scratch too. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may have figured out the solution to this problem. In my case Eclipse was set to use version 2.3 instead of 3.0 of the Dynamic Web Module.

I solved this by right clicking my project, going to `Properties`. Under `Project Facets` untick `Dynamic Web Module` and press apply. Then change the version number to `3.0` and retick and reapply. Once done, right click the project, go to `Maven` and press `Update Project...`.

Answer (score 1):

All xsd schemas that you can use are stored inside some jar file. In this case it will be `spring-security-config-3.2.0.M2.jar`. Open it in Eclipse (Project Explorer -> Your project -> Java Resources -> Libraries -> Maven Dependencies -> spring-security-config-3.2.0.M2.jar).
You can find the list of available schemas in `META-INF/spring.schemas` file. Normally all shcemas are in `org.springframework.security.config` package (for example `org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-3.1.xsd`). Make sure that you use one of schemas available there. If it is not the case then update your security xml file. Othervice if you can find corresponding file then it is the problem with Eclipse (Project -> Clean).

Comment: Hi Maksym, thanks for the reply. I've already had a look at that file, and it seems that what I am using (spring-security.xsd) is mapped to the -3.2.xsd file. I've also tried adding -3.2 myself, as well as the others without any luck. Cleaning the project in Eclipse unfortunately doesn't solve the problem too.

Comment: I do have another maven related question though. When adding a dependency into the pom.xml file, maven seems to try to grab the library file from a folder it creates under my profile (user/.m2/repository). What I have been doing is putting the jar into those folders and going to maven -> update project in Eclipse. This seems to get rid of the pom.xml errors, but is that all I need to do? Maybe it's the way I'm adding the jars that is causing this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Normally you do not need to modify anything in `/.m2/repository` folder. All you need to do is declare new depency in pom.xml and save it. In Eclipse with all necessary Maven plugins `mvn dependency:resolve` will be called for you automatically (corresponding new jar will be downloaded then stored in /.m2/repository and added to eclipse project as library).

Comment: Where is your xml header? `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: That's strange. Eclipse didn't automatically download the dependencies for me. Do you have to set up the repository location inside the pom.xml?

In regards to the xml header, I originally had it but noticed some strange warning appearing in my error log. I looked it up and someone suggested adding this to the <properties> tag in the pom.xml file instead: `<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>`. I just re-added the xml header and the warning doesn't seem to be there anymore. The namespacehandler warning still remains though.

Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Thanks for the help. +1 for trying. I ended up redoing the project from scratch, this time using the version of spring that maven has in their own repositories (so it auto-downloads the jars) and I don't seem to be getting the warning anymore.